# What is this use of void about?

Tags: type-conversion, void, void-pointers

In C++, `void` is used to specify a function with no return value. Then there are *void pointers*, which can be used to point to almost any variable, no matter the type. There is also *casting to void*, which may come in handy, if you want to suppress warnings of unused function return values.

However, in addition to all those uses mentioned above, there seems to be a use case for `void`-keyword, which I'm unaware of. This use case exists in the following code (*appears in Mesa GL source code*):

```
class count_block_size : public program_resource_visitor {
public:
   count_block_size() : num_active_uniforms(0)
   {
      /* empty */
   }

   unsigned num_active_uniforms;

private:
   virtual void visit_field(const glsl_type *type, const char *name,
                            bool row_major)
   {
      (void) type;
      (void) name;
      (void) row_major;
      this->num_active_uniforms++;
   }
};
```

This use of void near the end of this piece of code perplexes me. What is `void` in parentheses used for here?

Answer (score 0):

It appears casting to `void` has been used here to eliminate warnings about unused variables. Some compilers and/or settings provide such warnings. So, casting to void here does none other than silence the compiler about possible warnings.